# extract GET parameters from a user inputed url with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to use javascript to extract the GET parameters from a user inputed url.

For example is a user enters a url say:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ee925OTFBCA

I could get the v parameter

'ee925OTFBCA' as a variable

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there are so many open questions on this, did you even bother looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
// include this somewhere available 
var Query = (function(){
    var query = {}, pair, search = location.search.substring(1).split("&"), i = search.length;
    while (i--) {
        pair = search[i].split("=");
        query[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return query;
})();


var v= Query["v"]
```

This only runs its computation once and creates an object with name/value pairs corresponding to those supplied as parameters

Comment: Nice one - and only needs to decode once as opposed to the other posts here.

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple values. It works to answer this specific question, but not as a general purpose solution.

Comment: Guffa: what? Go read up on your DOM/javascript. The search field was never intended to convey multiple parameters with identical names.

Comment: The browser happily submits multiple values for identical names, and cgis can handle them fine too, even though perl modules like CGI.pm presume you cannot have multiple identical names.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://mattwhite.me/11tmr.nsf/D6Plinks/MWHE-695L9Z):

```
function getURLParam(strParamName){
  var strReturn = "";
  var strHref = window.location.href;
  if ( strHref.indexOf("?") > -1 ){
    var strQueryString = strHref.substr(strHref.indexOf("?")).toLowerCase();
    var aQueryString = strQueryString.split("&");
    for ( var iParam = 0; iParam < aQueryString.length; iParam++ ){
      if (
aQueryString[iParam].indexOf(strParamName.toLowerCase() + "=") > -1 ){
        var aParam = aQueryString[iParam].split("=");
        strReturn = aParam[1];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return unescape(strReturn);
}
```

To use it:

```
 var v = getURLParam('v')
```

Comment: location.search gives you the ?xxxx part - if no location.search, no questionmark there

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r.push(m[1]);
   return r;
}
```

Example:

```
var v = querystring('v')[0];
```

The function returns an array with all the values found in the query string. If you have a query string like `?x=0&v=1&v=2&v=3` the call `querystring('v')` returns an array with three items.

Comment: window.location.search is the one to use in my opinion
document.location is now document.URL

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple snippet:

```
function extractParamValue(url, name) {
    var pos = url.indexOf(name+'=')+name.length+1;
    var value = url.substring(pos, url.indexOf('&', pos));
    return value;
}
```