# Url query string to Object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the function below, which puts the query into an object. It works but adds the url to the object and Im not really regex savy enough to work out how to remove the url and only include the vars.

```
function urlToObj(url)
{
        var obj = {};
        url.replace(
            new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
            function($0, $1, $2, $3) { obj[$1] = $3; }
        );

        return obj;
}
```

E.g.

```
url = http://www.example.com/hello/world.php?var1=1&var2=2
url = http://www.example.com/hello/world.asp?var1=1&var2=2
url = http://www.example.com/hello/world?var1=1&var2=2

obj = urlToObj(url);
```

Output

```
obj { var1="1", var2="2", http://www.example.com/hello/world.php="" }
obj { var1="1", var2="2", http://www.example.com/hello/world.asp="" }
obj { var1="1", var2="2", http://www.example.com/hello/world="" }
```

I would like it to remove the urls so it looks like this

```
obj { var1="1", var2="2" }
```

Any examples and info where I am going wrong would be great.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [extract GET parameters from a user inputed url with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843813/extract-get-parameters-from-a-user-inputed-url-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension creates a singleton query string object for quick and readable query string modification and creation. This plugin provides a simple way of taking a page's query string and creating a modified version of this with little code.

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

Comment: I am having a little trouble figuring out how to load the url to the plugin. I know you can use $.query.set("section", 5).set("action", "do").toString(); but I have a large query, there must be a way to load a url and not add each var. What have i missed.

Answer (score 0):

What about some hack? :-)

```
function urlToObj ( url ) {
    var obj = {};
    url.replace(
        new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) { obj[$1] = $3; }
    );

    // Now, you know you've got an empty string for your url
    // So let's loop through the object and remove this property
    for ( var prop in obj ) {

        // You only want the objects properties, nothing inherited
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {

            // If it's an empty string
            if ( obj[ prop ] === '' ) {

                // Delete it!
                delete obj[ prop ]
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hack ;) But need to use the plugin incase of arrays in the query. Cant figure it out though, seem you have to add each var to the obj which seem pointless to me.